# How to fit rails_admin into my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I have a rails3 app with my custom layout. I integrated rails_admin into my application. In config/routes.rb I mount my application on RailsAdmin::Engine. now my application take the rails_admin layout. But my intention is to fit only the rails_admin dashboard table view into my layout. And also I don't want to include the side navigation bars. How to configure rails_admin to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding my layout files into app/views/rails_admin. Now I got the expected layout.